# Return function field value in onchange method

Tags: return, odoo, onchange, openerp-7

How can i return function field value from onchange method? Is it necessary to defined field as store=True?

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a function field on onchange. 
Even if its set store=True, it will only calculate once the record is finally saved.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are lacking somewhere in functionality. function fields are supposed to auto calculate at the time of record is saved. If you need to change that on on_change then change field type, it doesn't make sense to be function type.

No, it is not necessary to define function fields with store=True, you can store it on a condition ( when value of a field changes) or you can not store function field. it will be calculated at the time of record loading.